# AJAX call to make an HTTP request

Tags: javascript, node.js, http, express.js

I am using node.js with express. There is a button that the user can click, and doing so calls this method on the server:

```
app.get('/getTime', function(req, res) {

    var url = 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/gettime';
    http.get(url + '?key=' + apikey, function(resp) {

        var xml = '';
        resp.on('data', function(chunk) {
            xml += chunk;
        });

    resp.on('end', function() {
            console.log(xml);
            res.send(xml);
        });

    });

});
```

This works, strictly speaking, in that the client side does receive the XML data. What bothers me is that there are two response objects that I have only dealt with by calling one "res" and the other "resp". I have a feeling I am handling the callbacks the wrong way, or that the entire structure of this task is done incorrectly.

I would appreciate some guidance about the "right way" to do this, as I am sure this is not it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the HTTP response implements [`Writable Stream`](http://nodejs.org/api/stream.html#stream_class_stream_writable) and Express wraps around [HTTP](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html), you can pipe the output to the response, like so:

```
app.get('/getTime', function(req, res) {
    var url = 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/gettime';

    http.get(url + '?key=' + apikey, function(incoming) {
        incoming.pipe(res);
    }
});
```

It will not only cut down on latency times but also cut down on lines of code.

Comment: That's excellent, thanks very much. I knew there was something I wasn't quite seeing and this is it.

Answer (score 0):

From a once over:

- Your indenting is off, try something like [jsbeautifier.org](http://jsbeautifier.org)
- Dont do `console.log` in production code, it is synchronous and slow
- Other than that your code is very typical, there is nothing obviously wrong

Furthermore, would this work for you ?

```
app.get('/getTime', function(req, res) {
  var url = 'http://www.ctabustracker.com/bustime/api/v1/gettime';
  http.get(url + '?key=' + apikey, res);
});
```

Since you are anyway sending the data thru, I wonder if this would work.